# Need help identifying the 4 microphone wires in my laptop webcam

Tags: usb, microphone, camera, diy, laptop

I am trying to adapt my laptop's webcam into a USB webcam. Although I couldn't find any schematics online, the manufacturer did print (I assume) labels to identify the 8 wires coming out of the webcam.[image: Back of webcam]

If possible I want to have the microphone work. I'm assuming I will need to wire it up to both a USB (power and camera) and a 3.5mm jack (mic). The two problems I am facing is knowing which ground I should solder to the USB and what the 3 Mic wires are for. (Googling has only shown me about headsets with 1 mic wire for a 3.5mm jack.)

Does anyone know what the C/D/P stands for? Google has not helped so far. For the ground problem, I think the GND wire closest to the data +/- wires is for my USB connection, but the line drawn connecting the other GND to V33D wire has me less confident. (Which is for the MIC?)

I know wire colouring doesn't mean anything, but in case anyone has the same model the colours are as follows:

```
GND     white
MIC_C   purple
MIC_D   blue
MIC_P   green
GND     yellow
DP      black
DM      orange
V33D    red
```

Comment: Is the mic signal from the board analogue or digital?  Are you sure the camera output is usb compatible?

Comment: 3.3V instead of 5V, and DP/DM and Ground, indicates it's a usb camera. The mic is likely not a simple one as newer mics have multiple microphones and advance canceling or multispatial features.

Comment: The line indicates the connector body. And the 1 indicates pin 1. Colors don't matter.

Comment: @Passerby If mic is complex as you say I probably wont bother.
Thanks for explaining the pin markings, I'll just give it a go with the GND that is wired closest. Worst that happens is the webcam fries when I test it.

Comment: My guesses are "clock", "data" and "power". It's not I2S because that requires an additional "word clock". (unless P is the word clock, but how do you get the letter P from that?) Might be I2C or PCM or something. If you have an oscilloscope and the laptop still works, you could watch how the laptop interacts with the microphone.

Comment: @user253751 Unfortunately the motherboard is completely dead, so I won't be able to test that. Your guesses sound reasonable though!

Comment: I had the same idea as Frank this week. I wanted to reuse the internal camera of an old laptop as webcam and found this module. After several attempts I did not succeed to get it running. Frank did you succeed to get it running in the end?

Answer (score 0):

As user253751 said.
Had same idea so instead searched for smd mic connections and got the schematic. P-power, D-data and C-clock.
https://www.cuidevices.com/blog/analog-or-digital-how-to-choose-the-right-mems-microphone-interface